# How to Flag for Follow Up using Java Mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have a java mail sender which I wanted to set a follow-up reminder rules.. Like how we wil set in outlook.Please help is there any way I can set in java mail??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [Reply-By](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4021#section-2.1.51) MIME header as the date of the deadline and the non-standard [X-Message-Flag](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/466d3413-4d3a-4898-9665-da8e7e4b4593/sending-email-marked-as-followup-through-c-code?forum=csharpgeneral) to signal the reason as `Follow up`.  Here is an example code fragment:

```
final long REPLY_BY_MS = 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L; //One day.
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setHeader("X-Message-Flag", "Follow up");
javax.mail.internet.MailDateFormat md 
        = new javax.mail.internet.MailDateFormat();
final long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
msg.setHeader("Reply-By", md.format(new Date(now + REPLY_BY_MS)));
msg.setSentDate(new Date(now));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about java mail but I've experimented with tools like https://hubspot.com/ to help with this and also use https://unreplied.io because I use Gmail and it just works behind the scene to sort emails into an "Unreplied" bucket for me.

There's also a really good article with follow up email templates here: https://www.hubspot.com/sales/follow-up-email